# Data is being inserted, but cannot find the query history in v$sql table. (Oracle 11g 11.2.0.2.0)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, scheduler

I'm trying to find a Spring scheduled process which inserts data into a particular table,
but cannot find the WAS server that the spring application is running on.

So I tried to track the Spring application by the running queries,
which can be joined with the sessions table(v$session) to get machine name or other information.

```
SELECT
    v.SQL_TEXT,
    v.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
    v.LAST_LOAD_TIME,
    v.DISK_READS,
    v.ROWS_PROCESSED,
    v.ELAPSED_TIME,
    v.service,
    v.MODULE
FROM
    v$sql v
WHERE
    to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')>ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'),-2)
    AND LOWER(SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%[the_table_name]%'
    AND LOWER(SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%insert %'
ORDER BY
    FIRST_LOAD_TIME DESC
```

The scheduled process runs every minute,
but I couldn't find the query that inserts data into the target table.

Am I doing something wrong?
Or is there a way to insert data without logging in the v$sql table?

Comment: V$ tables are not history tables. They are real-time views of what's happening in the database. SQL will only be visible there while it is shared_pool, which may be longer for some commands than for others. Oracle has internal algorithms to determine how long certain commands are retained there. Some statements may only be visible there for the fraction of a second they are being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pmdba mentioned, `v$sql` is volatile. DDL's never show up, and other cursors are removed on an as-needed basis. But as you say you are querying every minute, you certainly should see your SQL.

1. First, you are asking only for recently loaded cursors. It is possible that your insert was first parsed and loaded into the shared pool many months ago. I can't recall if `LAST_ACTIVE_TIME` was introduced already in 11.2 or not, but if it was, use that instead and look at the last few minutes. Otherwise, remove the date filter.
2. Secondly, you mentioned that you are joining to `v$session`, though your SQL above doesn't show that. Don't join to `v$session` - the inserting sessions may be very short and no longer present. If you need to see (recent) history, you can query `v$active_session_history` once you know the `SQL_ID`.
3. Thirdly, find out if it's a clustered RAC database (query `gv$instance`, if you get more than one row, you're in RAC). If you are, you will need to use `gv$sql`, not `v$sql`, as you may be querying on a different instance than the application is connecting to.
4. Fourthly, you can insert rows using a `MERGE` statement, so check for those too... not just `INSERT`.
5. Fifthly, you are looking for the table name, but you can insert through a synonym or a view. Look for any synonyms pointing to the table, or any views over the table and check for inserts or merges into them.
6. Lastly, check v$sql_plan so you can get a positive match on the actual physical table name:

   ```
    SELECT *
      FROM v$sql_plan
     WHERE (operation LIKE '%INSERT%' OR operation LIKE '%LOAD%' OR operation LIKE '%MERGE%' OR operation LIKE '%UPSERT%')
       AND object_name = '[table name]'
   ```

If you find it, get the `sql_id` and look in `gv$sql` and then figure out why your query wasn't finding it.

Hope these ideas help.